# Get the single element from the array

Tags: php, arrays, database, element

I got the following array (the array is retrieved through a db query). Now, my question is, how do I get a single element like `e_domains` from the array mentioned below:

```
   stdClass Object
    (
     [id] => 1
     [uni_origin] => Aachen
     [e_domains] => rwth-aachen.de
    )
```

I got the output shown above by running the following line of codes:

```
 if ($results ) {
   foreach ( $results as $result ){
      echo'<pre>'; print_r($result) ;
   }
}
```

Comment: It's is object array print echo $result[0]->id

Comment: How do you get result from DB?

Comment: Have you logged out or given up? Are we talking to ourselves?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, that's not an array, that's an object. Like it says: "stdClass **Object**".

Access object properties like this:

```
$object->property_name
```

In your case, it would be:

```
$result->e_domains
```

There are much more to learn on the subject, like static properties, visibility etc. In your case, the above example will work.

Read more about classes and objects in the manual: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
$e_domains = mysql_result(mysql_query("SELECT id FROM games LIMIT 1"),0);
```

Hope it helpt.

Comment: how does this answer the question?

Comment: You do know that the old and insecure `mysql_*`-functions are deprecated since PHP 5.5 and completely removed in PHP 7, right? Plus, it doesn't answer the OP's question. Btw, how would you even get the actual domains if all you're selecting is the `id` column'?